# unable to find mojo sonar (or one of its component) in the plugin org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

I am implementing sonar in my existing maven project.I am getting this error :

> unable to find mojo sonar (or one of its component) in the plugin org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin

Following are my configs:

- Maven version:2.2.1
- Java version:1.6
- sonar-maven-plugin version:3.0.2
- sonarcube version:6.4
- sonar java version: 4.10.0.10260

I have updated:

- `pom.xml`
- `settings.xml`
- `sonar-project.properties`

to mentioned my intended java version in it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include SonarQube version (found in the page footer) and SonarJava version (found in **Administration > System > Update Center**)

Comment: I setup a local project with your exact same setup and cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I have updated as u said.

Comment: @slartidan thanks for commenting. Is your maven sonar build successfully completing?

Comment: I tried with Maven 3, Java 1.6, SonarQube 6.4 and sonar-java 4.10.0.10260. Actually I did not try with Maven 2. Maybe @g-ann-sonarsource-team is right...

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Java 7 and Maven 3, and this should work.